# Clipboard Issues with Windows WSL2 GUI Apps (WSLg)

Tags: clipboard, gui, wsl2, x-windows

WSL2 now has built-in xserver [wslg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg), but just like reported [here](https://emacsredux.com/blog/2022/01/04/dealing-with-clipboard-issues-on-windows-11-wslg/),

I'm having difficulties letting apps in wslg to sync their x-clipboard content with normal Windows' clipboard.

I know there might not be solutions at the moment, but I'd like to at least confirm if it not only happening to me, as someone in above url says *"I never had this problem with clipboard"*.

**UPDATE:**

The usage scenario is simply `xterm` / `xedit` using x-clipboard. [This Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237942/how-does-copy-paste-work-with-xterm/) gives a very good summary of it:

- Left-down-clicking in xterms starts the selection of something to be copy-pasted.
- Double-left clicking selects a word.
- Triple-left clicking selects a line.

To paste, Use middle click or <kbd>Shift + Insert</kbd>

See [X Window selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection).

Using my own xserver, the x-clipboard content is syncing with normal Windows' clipboard all the time, and it is bi-directional. However, with WSL2 / wslg, if I update Windows' clipboard with something new, and try to paste in to `xterm` / `xedit`, it doesn't work -- what get pasted is the x-clipboard of wslg. I get this same behavior with both Ubuntu-22.04 and Debian (bullseye) in WSL2.

Comment: Well, getting 3 of your 4 questions yesterday wasn't bad ;-)  As for this one, I've definitely had both successes and failures with the X clipboard under WSLg.  I don't use it all that much, but I think I was to the point the last time I tried it that I was more successful than not.  I saw that Emacs report when I was investigation a few months ago, but I never tried to reproduce that one in particular.  Do you have a particular scenario that isn't working for you?  Assuming it doesn't have too many dependencies, I'd be happy to try to reproduce and/or troubleshoot.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @NotTheDr01ds, really appreciate your help. The scenario is simply xterm / xedit. I'll update OP to explain more there.

Comment: In case it helps, `wl-copy`/`wl-paste` works fine for me but I'm experiencing issues with `xclip` on neovim. Luckily for me I just need to install the `wl-clipboard` package and neovim system clipboard now works perfectly.

Comment: `wl-copy`/`wl-paste` is failing with *Failed to connect to a Wayland server* for me.